# Does the Atnah/Etnahtah Denote Emphasis

Tags: grammar-dikduk, trop-cantillation

Im learning with a new te'amim teacher. He mentioned that one cant rely on the atnah / etnahta symbol to show syllabic emphasis. He also said that the symbol never shows up on the end of a word. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: Deny: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66386/759

Comment: "He also said that the symbol never shows up on the end of a word." Do you mean the last letter or the last syllable? Gen 1:1 has it on the last syllable. And 1:2 and 1:3 and.....

Answer (score 3):

Among the *te'amim* used in the majority of *Tanakh*, the only *te'amim* that **can** be written **not** on an accented syllable are *pashṭa*, *telisha*, *segol*, and *zarqa* (additionally, *yetiv* is pre-posed, although it only falls on words with initial stress), as noted in [Wickes' list of te'amim](https://books.google.com/books?id=bIgrAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA10), and in R' Breuer's *ta'amei hamiqra*, א-25 and א-38.

Among the *te'amim* used in Psalms, Proverbs, and Job, the only *te'mim* that **can** be written **not** on an accented syllable are *tsinnor* and *deḥi* (and the "secondary" sign in *te'amim* with two signs: *'ole veyored* and *revi'a mugrash*), as noted in [Wickes' list of te'amim](https://books.google.com/books?id=qbkIAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA12).

The *etnaḥta* can fall on the last syllable of a word, as in Gen 1:1, 1:2, 1:3, and 1:4. It can even fall on the last letter of a word, as in Gen 24:57 (although this is in some ways a cheat, as נער pronounced as נערה is a *qere perpetuum*).

Comment: When does yetiv not fall on the stressed syllable?  I thought yetiv only appears when the stress is on the first syllable (either it's one syllable, or it's two syllables and mile'eil).

Comment: @Heshy Consider שְׁ֚תַּיִם [Lev 23 17](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0323.htm) as a Yetiv not on the accented letter.

Comment: @DoubleAA the placement for שתים can still arguably be "on the first syllable", although I agree.

Comment: @magicker72 It could arguably be on the first syllable but only in the sense which you aren't trying to discuss. Any other ordinary note would be marked on the Tav there, but Yetiv is different. Find whatever word works for you to describe the difference, but there is a definitely a real difference.

Comment: This is interesting info. Do any of the sources that you list discuss WHY the rules are this way? Also, of the two sources you listed, which is easier for a "beginner" to understand. I.e., I am an experienced Torah reader, but I don't fully understand the grammar behind the trope.

Comment: @DanF One suggestion is that the *segol* would make the word very busy, and the other ones could be easily confused with other similar/identical-looking *te'amim*.