What is the pronunciation of these nikkud?
I am trying to learn Hebrew pronunciation by reading Rashi's commentary on the Torah. However, the Torah’s text in this version of the book has a lot of Nikkud which I cannot find an explanation.  Namely, the only Nikkud whose pronunciations I found online are:

Hiriq ( ִ )
(Hataf) Kamatz ( ָ / ֳ )
(Hataf) Patakh ( ַ / ֲ )
(Hataf) Segol ( ֶ / ֱ )
Tzere ( ֵ )
Shva ( ְ )
Kubutz ( ֻ )
Shuruk (ּו)
Full / Lacking Hulam (וֹ/חֹ )
Dagesh ( ּ )

However, in this book, there are a lot of Nikkud which are not in the above list.  For example, on the attached page, there are (starting on the last line of the 2nd column and going up)(and I am describing the Nikkud since I don't know their name):

< underneath
Magnifying glass on the top
| underneath
` underneath
/\ underneath
·/ underneath
/ underneath

And also, in the same column, starting from the top line and going down:

/ on top
. on top
: on top
` on top
ד underneath

How do I pronounce these?  Or do they have a use other than pronunciation?
Page illustrating the above-mentioned Nikkud:


https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_cantillation

Note that (I think) everything you are describing is in the Torah text (above the line) rather than in Rashi’s commentary (below the line)

Yes, it's in the Torah text only (I noticed that too, but I should've said so in the question maybe?) The article says they affect the melody, but doesn't really explain how.  So basically, if I understand correctly, they do not affect pronunciation at all, if I'm simply reading?

Correct. No effect on the pronunciation of individual words. Aside for the melody, they also function like punctuation marks, indicating pauses in the same way as commas, semicolons and periods etc.

@JoelK They (usually) indicate word stress (ie which syllable gets the accent) which is plausibly part of pronunciation

@DoubleAA I can accept your answer if you add how the cantillations turn into accents.  For example, the last cantillation on both of the last 2 lines in the 2nd column fall on consonants, which have no vowels to accent.  Also, e.g. 2nd line of 2nd column, there are words with multiple cantillations -- which one gets accented then?

@Alex There are about 4-5 notes which are always written on the first or last letter, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86498/759 or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66386/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97779/759. The word רָעָב֙ has a pashta note, which is one of those exceptions.

Here’s a link describing the melodies for Ta’amim in three common traditions: https://tikunkorim.co.il/learn-teamim

Here’s a Syrian Jewish website with a rudimentary explanation of the grammatical functions of each trop symbol: https://pizmonim.org/taamim.php. The recordings at the bottom of the page are of the Syrian melodies for cantillation.

@DoubleAA, many newer chumashim print a redundant one on the stressed syllable, though I don't know if this one (the old interlinear Rashi) does

@NoachMiFrankfurt Even those that do, probably wouldn't on רָעָב֙ since the word is milra so the accent isn't ambiguous, even if it might be a bit clearer on the ע. If the accent was on the ר then yes they would.

@DoubleAA, of course not, but then the pashta/similarly placed trop is on the stressed syllable, even if it's not the same letter as it might otherwise be

Tangentially, what you called “the 2nd column” is actually the first column. Hebrew texts go from right to left.

The symbols you're describing are cantillation marks, or "trop." As Joel K noted, Wikipedia has a rundown of them (with melodies according to the Eastern Ashkenazi usage).
The long and short is that the various symbols are punctuation indicating syntactical groupings (with sof-passuk (אֽ׃) and etnachtah (א֑) being the strongest pauses) and (in most cases) indicating where the proper word stress should be. There are other resources on Mi Yodeya for trop; I can try to add them to this answer, later.
